# How do I join on a constant in LINQ?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to do a left join on a constant like this:

```
SELECT 
    [t0].[DeviceId], 
    [t0].[DeviceTypeId], 
    [t0].[UnitId], 
    [t0].[UnitNum], 
    [t0].[ManPhone], 
    [t0].[Status], 
    [t2].[MaintDate] AS [ServiceExpiration]
FROM [dbo].[Devices] AS [t0]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[CustomerDevices] AS [t1] 
        ON ([t0].[DeviceId]) = [t1].[DeviceId]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Maintenance] AS [t2] 
        ON ([t0].[DeviceId]) = [t2].[DeviceId]
            AND 8 = [t2].ActionId
```

I get a [CS1941](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513747.aspx) when I attempt it in LINQ like this:

```
var devices = from d in db.Devices
    join cd in db.CustomerDevices
        on d.DeviceId equals cd.DeviceId
    join serviceExpiration in db.Maintenances
        on 
           new { d.DeviceId, ActionId = 8 } // CS1941
               equals 
           new { serviceExpiration.DeviceId, ActionId = serviceExpiration.ActionId } into j1
    from deviceServiceExpiration in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try from Maintenances on `ActionId == 8` first, then use this to join against.

```
var expirations = from serviceExpiration in db.Maintenances
                  where serviceExpiration.ActionId == 8
                  select serviceExpiration;

var devices = from d in db.Devices
    join cd in db.CustomerDevices
        on d.DeviceId equals cd.DeviceId
    join e in expirations
        on d.DeviceId = e.DeviceId into j1
    from deviceServiceExpiration in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select deviceServiceExpiration;
```

Comment: In this case, the = is correct because I'm assigning a value to a property in an anonymous type.

Your recommendation works, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
var devices = from d in db.Devices
    join cd in db.CustomerDevices
        on d.DeviceId equals cd.DeviceId
    join serviceExpiration in db.Maintenances
        on d.DeviceId equals serviceExpiration.DeviceId into j1
    from deviceServiceExpiration in j1.Where(c=>c.ActionId ==8).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but I ran into the same issue and wanted to help anyone in the future.
The fix is to join to a sub-query.

```
var devices = from d in db.Devices
    join cd in db.CustomerDevices
        on d.DeviceId equals cd.DeviceId
    join serviceExpiration in (from x in db.Maintenances where x.ActionId == 8 select x)
        on d.DeviceId equals serviceExpiration.DeviceId into j1
    from deviceServiceExpiration in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

or within the query:

```
var devices = from d in db.Devices
    join cd in db.CustomerDevices
        on d.DeviceId equals cd.DeviceId
    join serviceExpiration in db.Maintenances
        on 
           d.DeviceId
               equals 
           serviceExpiration.DeviceId into j1
    from deviceServiceExpiration in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where serviceExpiration.ActionId  == 8
    select deviceServiceExpiration;
```

Comment: This will make the ActionID == 8 part of the where clause, which will filter out any devices that don't have an Maintenance record of type 8.